# How can I allow a snap application to execute a custom script

Tags: snap

I have a Nextcloud server that was installed via snap [(Github page)](https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap). It has run quite well so far, but now I would like to start using Nextcloud's workflow feature to run a script when a new mkv file is created (Very simple script that executes ffmpeg and just converts the file from an mkv container to mp4).

However this is where my knowledge of snap ends. The snap has no access to the script I've created, and also doesn't have permissions to execute ffmpeg. Is there a way to give snap the access it needs to run ffmpeg and my script?

Comment: AFAIK, the developer is responsible for doing this by building the snap with the classical packaging. Normal packaging mode completely sandboxes the program, so it can't execute anything on the machine.

Comment: [Rant] My experience is that snap incapacitates you.[/Rant] Try to install it without snap.

Comment: Read the errors in syslog: Is this a permission-denied error due to the *location*, or due to the *activity*, or something else?

Comment: A snap package (that is not `classic`) is separate from the rest of the applications of your system. Therefore, the `ffmpeg` executable is not accessible from within the snap. 

Just like GIMP plugins, you can run plugins from within the GIMP snap, but the plugins need to be statically linked because they cannot access any of the libraries of the system.

Comment: @kanehekili Ugh.  This really ticks me off.  Why does Ubuntu *insist* on having so many packages as snaps when I wind up being unable to do the things I need to do, *and* then am asked to jump through a bunch of hoops to get my work done.  This is *not* user friendly, and even as an "expert" I find this tiresome and almost too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Based on everyone's comments. It sounds like in order to give snap permission to execute ffmpeg and my script, I would either need to A) redo my implementation as a "writable snap" per the nextcloud-snap documentation, or B) stop using snap altogether (I'm not tied to snap, but I'm also not interested in redoing my nextcloud installation at this time). So I can't use my script through nextcloud's workflow feature as-implemented. However, I did find a workaround for my scenario. My script just needs access to run ffmpeg on my stored nextcloud data, and the snap *does* allow me to designate an external data directory where my nextcloud data can be stored. So I did the following

1. I copied my data to an external directory, pointed snap to use that data directory per [These instructions](https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap/wiki/Change-data-directory-to-use-another-disk-partition)
2. Set up an incron job to execute my script when a new file is uploaded via nextcloud. My incrontab entry looks like this `/mnt/nextcloud/data/directory/ IN_ATTRIB ~/bin/my_script.sh $@$#`
3. As the final step in my script, I instruct nextcloud to scan for new files in my destination directory by running `/snap/bin/nextcloud.occ files:scan --path="username/videos/converted` (note: path is relative to the nextcloud username)

Comment: **Without snap** you could've installed it [this](https://markus-blog.de/index.php/2021/07/08/how-to-install-nextcloud-hub-22-on-ubuntu-20-04-with-postgresql-13-php8-0-fpm-apache2-and-http-2/) way.